# What steps do you take when an Administrator leaves your organization?

Tags: active-directory

This question goes out to the network/system admins;

What are the steps which you take once another administrator (or anyone with administrative privileges) leaves the organization?

The objective is to properly remove the administrator from the system. I also hope to locate everywhere within AD that the previous Admin's password has been applied so that they can be changed.

Comment: Look at questions pointed out by @ChrisS, plus read Limoncelli/Hogan/Chalup, ch.36.

Comment: I am a brand new system admin (fresh out of school, a true greenhorn). The previous admin which I am replacing did not quite follow any best practices, nor did he really document much of anything.

Answer (score 4):

Information is scattered around the site, I don't think I can close this as a duplicate of any 1 Question.

We have several good Questions already, dealing with aspects of an administrator leaving:

- [The IT Manager is Leaving - What do I lockdown?](https://serverfault.com/questions/29633/the-it-manager-is-leaving-what-do-i-lockdown)
- [How do you search for backdoors from the previous IT person?](https://serverfault.com/questions/171893/how-do-you-search-for-backdoors-from-the-previous-it-person)
- [How do I protect my company from my IT guy?](https://serverfault.com/questions/283909/how-do-i-protect-my-company-from-my-it-guy)
- [Steps to take when technical staff leave](https://serverfault.com/questions/285723/steps-to-take-when-technical-staff-leave)

Additionally, nobody should know the "main" administrator password. You should have at least two people use a random password generator, each writes down their half, types it in, then seal the two halves in an envelope (preferably in the company safe). Nobody knows the whole password this way.

It sounds like you probably aren't the system admin, but have been drafter on account of that person quitting (or whatever). The next person should have a read through [The Practice of System and Network Administration](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321492668). It's as close as it comes to the System Administrator's bible, which covers this sort of situation and gives insight into mitigating the problems you're having.